flutter camera plugin requests microphone permission
I read how do manually remove microphone phone permission for camera plugin in flutter
but without success even though I added enableaudio: false my app still requests microphone permission, I use the barcode scanner code from: the google ml kit
Here's my _startlivefeed function:
Future _startLiveFeed() async {
    final camera = _cameras[_cameraIndex];
    _controller = CameraController(
      camera,
      ResolutionPreset.high,
      enableAudio: false,
      imageFormatGroup: Platform.isAndroid
          ? ImageFormatGroup.nv21
          : ImageFormatGroup.bgra8888,
    );

    await _controller?.initialize();

    if (_controller?.value.isInitialized == true) {
      await _controller?.startImageStream(_processCameraImage);
      if (widget.onCameraFeedReady != null) {
        widget.onCameraFeedReady!();
      }
      setState(() {});
    }
  }


You can refer to this thread and it might be helpful for you thread link

They write to use enableAudio: false, which does not work for me :(

But why do you need to remove microphone permission? In the official camera package documentation, they said if you make enableAudio false then you can't include audio while recording video.

Still the app still requests microphone permission.

Ok. But I have one question why you don't require microphone permission?

I just need the picture not audio.
